# To north and west of the hill are steep slopes to the Rivers Eden and Calder respectively

Tags: sentence-construction

> **To north and west of the hill are steep slopes to the Rivers Eden and
>   Calder respectively**; on the east lies the River Petterill, while some
>   kilometres further north the Solway forms the natural boundary to the
>   Scottish lowlands.*

What's the original sentence of it?

The steep slopes (to north and west of the hill) are to the Rivers Eden and Calder respectively ?

or

The steep slopes (to the Rivers Eden and Calder respectively) are to north and west of the hill?

--update--

thank you for all the help. I learned a lot. But what I am confused was the sentence structure. let me rephrase my question.

if making it as prep phrase1 + verb + subject + prep phrase2, does it always make equal meaning in interpreting the sentence as

S(PP1)+V+PP2

S(PP2)+V+PP1

Hope I have made the question clear this time.

---

<sub>* Source: [The Small Towns of Roman Britain](https://books.google.com/books?id=YBrqtfWkMsIC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22To+north+and+west+of+the+hill+are+steep+slopes+to+the+Rivers+Eden+and+Calder+respectively%22&source=bl&ots=BTmjyISNbW&sig=ACfU3U2_h_WBRBS32ydDVy1ALK-4LIWkfQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIsMvxyNbnAhUOLKwKHSPSCR0Q6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22To%20north%20and%20west%20of%20the%20hill%20are%20steep%20slopes%20to%20the%20Rivers%20Eden%20and%20Calder%20respectively%22&f=false)</sub>

Comment: As far as I can tell the meaning of your two interpretations are identical. In either case there is a slope to the North that goes to the River Eden and a slope to the West that goes to the River Calder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of [adverbial fronting and subject-verb inversion](https://www.eltbase.com/notes-538-fronting#99); the adverb phrase (*to the* north and west of the hill*) is at the front of the sentence, and the clause's subject (*steep slopes to the Rivers Eden and Calder*) comes after the verb (*are*) . . .

Normal order:

> *Steep slopes to the Rivers Eden and Calder are to the north and west of the hill respectively.*

Fronted order:

> *To the north and west of the hill are steep slopes to the Rivers Eden and Calder respectively.*

Either way, it means:

> *To the north of the hill, there is a steep slope to the River Eden, and to the west of the hill, there is a steep slope to the River Calder.*

---

* <sub>The authors appear to have inadvertently omitted the article *the*, as evidenced by their use of it in *the south* and *the east* on either side of this clause.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The original sentence would be

> There are steep slopes to north and west of the hill, to the Rivers Eden and Calder respectively.

The lack of article before *steep slopes* means that this does not equate to any sentence with the subject *the steep slopes*. It is introducing the slopes as a new topic, and the usual way of doing this would be with the presentative *there*. But because of the fronted modifier *to the north and west of the hill*, the "there" is optional.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any great difference between your two interpretations!

It states that there are steep slopes to the North and West.  The slope to the North goes down to the river Eden, and the slope to the West goes to the Calder.

This is consistent with both your interpretations. However the use of the word "respectively" refers the last phrase back to the first part, so you couldn't say "The steep slopes are to the rivers Eden and Calder respectively" as there is nothing for them to be "in respect to".